# Getting a Prefetch Abort after enabling MMU on ARMv7

Tags: caching, armv7, mmu

I am using Cortex A8 CPU on my board and am trying to map external SDRAM with address space `0x7000_0000` to `0x7FFF_FFFF` using 16M supersections. The MMU descriptor table of size 256 words (each entry in the table being `0x7005_1C0E`, `0x7105_1C0E`,....`0x7F05_1C0E`) is placed in the on-chip RAM at `0xF801_8000`. Since supersections are being used, each descriptor is repeated 16 times in the table - hence the size of the table is 256.
TTBCR.N is 0.
TTBR0 contains the same address which is `0xF801_8000`
When I enable the MMU by writing to the coprocessor, I get a prefetch abort.
Can someone help me figure out what I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: Where does your code reside and has that address space a valid mapping in your translation table? It sounds like that when you switch on the MMU, the next instruction fetch accesses an unmapped address resulting in that exception.

Comment: The code which sets up the MMU table and turns it on resides in the SDRAM space (0x7000_0000 to 0x7FFF_FFFF)

Comment: I changed the linker file so that the code now executes from OnChip RAM. Still same issue with a prefetch abort

Comment: Hmm, what about the cache? Do you invalidate the cache before you turn on the MMU?

Comment: yes. I-Cache, D-Cache and TLB invalidated before tunrning on the MMU

Comment: Following is the sequence of events:
Diasble MMU -> Disable I Cache -> Flush I Cahce -> Disable D Cache -> Invalidate & Flush D Cache -> Configure TTB -> Set TranslationTable base Address -> Set Domain 0 access rights to Master -> Build MMU Table -> Invalidate TLB -> Enable I Cache -> Enable D Cache -> Enable MMU